# Coffeescript - React setState not rendering after click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript

I am trying to change the text of a button when the user clicks on it.

The state changes but, the component does not seem to re-render

However, when I put the state in the upper level (in the outer if statement), the components text does change (but it would be in a separate view). I need to keep that component in that `else if` clause

Am I missing something or does this not work? I am still learning react and don't understand the whole concept of state and the deeper levels of state changes

```
render: ->

    if @state.couponSet == true and @state.couponSuccess != true
      div {},
        "Some view"
    else if @state.couponMode != true and @ state.couponSuccess != true
        div { className: "container" },
                SelectButton
                  clickHandler: @onSelectPlan.bind(null, this, 0)
                  wrapperClassName: 'button-wrapper'
                  className: 'plan-select'
                  buttonText: if @state.planSelected == true then "Selected" else "Select"
    else
        ...
```

And in `onSelectPlan`

```
onSelectPlan: (e, plan) ->
    if plan == 0
        @setState planSelected: true
```

Comment: this isnt' an answer to your question at all, but `if @state.couponSet == true and @state.couponSuccess != true` is somewhat redundant. more concisely it would read `if @state.couponSet and not @state.couponSuccess`

Comment: Oh, so you're saying I would not need the `==`  and `!=` operators? Thank you

Comment: correct, it's a little awkward to say `if true == true` or `if true is true`, it makes more sense to say `if true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your "bind" looks wrong.
You probably don't need the "bind" at all -- just use a fat arrow:

```
SelectButton
  clickHandler: (e, plan) =>
    if plan is 0
      @setState planSelected: true
```